# Issues with Node.js Website on EC2 Instance with ELB and Intranet Subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm currently facing challenges with my Node.js website deployed on an EC2 instance, utilizing an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) and configured with a subdomain that is accessible only within our organization.

I appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide.

Comment: Are you sure that the necessary ports are open to allow external traffic? also verify that your Node.js app is running correctly and listening on the right port. Additionally, confirm that the subdomain config points to the ELB and that the DNS records are set up for internal access...

Comment: @Yousha Aleayoub, everything is functioning correctly on my website. However, to enhance security, I've restricted access so that only our static IP address can reach the subdomain, ensuring it is not accessible publicly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.